# What is the PictureListener?

Tags: android, webview

What is the Android [WebView.PictureListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.PictureListener.html) and when is it called exactly? The documentation is quite vague about it.

Is the picture the content of the WebView? Is it called each time the content of the WebView changes (ie: each time a img element is loaded)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WebView does its rendering inside a Picture, which can be seen as a display list. The picture records everything the web page needs to draw: text, lines, images, etc. This listener can be used to be notified whenever the content of the WebView has changed *and* it's ready to be drawn.

Comment: PictureListener is currently deprecated. What should we use instead?